# Geodesics (1): Spaces with more than two geodesics between two points

Tags: geometry, riemannian-geometry

From the Wikipedia article on [geodesics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic#Introduction):

> In Riemannian geometry geodesics are not the same as “shortest curves”
>   between two points, though the two concepts are closely related. The
>   difference is that geodesics are only locally the shortest distance
>   between points [...]. Going
>   the “long way round” on a great circle between two points on a sphere
>   is a geodesic but not the shortest path between the points.

My question is:

> Are there (natural, Riemannian?) geometries with more than two geodesics
>   between two given points?

[Find a follow-up question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251918/geodesics-2-is-the-real-projective-plane-intended-to-make-shortest-paths-uniq).]

Comment: The wikipedia entry you cite gives the example of spheres. I don't understand what you are asking for, you already have an example. Do you want more? Any compact riemannian manifold will have many pairs of distinct points joined by several geodesics I believe. One way to see this, is to follow any geodesic farther than the radius of the manifold, then there'll be a second geodesic emanating from that point that intersects the first.

Comment: @Olivier: That's why I ask: on a sphere I can see - easily - *two* geodesics between two distinct points (along the great circle) but not *three*.

Comment: Take the north and south pole, there are more than two geodesics joining them, there are infinitely many.

Comment: @Olivier: you are - of course - absolutely right, and I didn't think of these exceptional cases. Can I make sense of my question by ignoring these exceptional cases: *Are there geometries with more than 2 but less than $\infty$ geodesics between two given points?*

Comment: @HansStricker: Yes, you can have any number.  Just make a sphere with $n$ equidistant bulging lumps at the equator.  A related thing you can ask for is the *dimension* of the space of such geodesics (considered as a subspace of the tangent space at the initial point) -- and this gets right to the heart of Morse theory.