# Geodesics (2): Is the real projective plane intended to make shortest paths unique?

Tags: geometry, riemannian-geometry, projective-geometry, geodesic

From the Wikipedia article on [geodesics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic#Introduction):

> In Riemannian geometry geodesics are not the same as “shortest curves”
>   between two points, though the two concepts are closely related. The
>   difference is that geodesics are only locally the shortest distance
>   between points [...]. Going
>   the “long way round” on a great circle between two points on a sphere
>   is a geodesic but not the shortest path between the points.

My question is:

> Can the construction of the [real projective plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_plane#Classical_examples) be understood – among other things – as an attempt to force shortest paths to be *unique*? (Like it can be understood as an attempt to force all straight lines to intersect.)

Antipodal points on a sphere
are exactly those points for which shortest paths are *not* unique.
Identifying them *does* make shortest paths unique.

[Find a follow-up question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251919/geodesics-3-a-projective-space-based-on-the-torus-instead-of-the-sphere).]

Comment: As you just saw in the comments on your other question, this isn't true.  I think the notion you're after is the "cut locus" or something like that -- given $p\in M$, this is the set of points for which there exists a unique shortest geodesic to $p$.  Equivalently, iirc, this is precisely the locus on which the exponential map $\exp:T_pM \to M$ is injective.

Comment: @Aaron: What exactly isn't true?

Comment: It isn't true that $\mathbb{R}P^2$ admits unique geodesics.  This is the case for *any* closed manifold -- the exponential map (at any given point) must eventually stop being injective.  The "injectivity radius" is the largest radius for which it *is* injective, which tells you the largest disk-neighborhood around your point for which unique geodesics still exist.